# CSS3 animation - the full cycle

Tags: css, animation

I've just got a problem making the CSS3 animations.

I've written the following code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes menu_styling_hover 
    from 
    {
        border-bottom-color:#F5B7B8;
        padding-top:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
    }
    to 
    {
        border-bottom-color:#FB7A7D;
        padding-top:6px;
        padding-bottom:6px;
    }
}
```

And I've attached this keyframe to the div with hover effect;

```
-webkit-animation:menu_styling_hover 0.3s linear;
animation:menu_styling_hover 0.3s linear;
```

It works fine. But when I unhover the element - it becomes to have previous characteristics without any animation of hiding it. So when the div is hovered, it has paddings 6px, and when I move mouse from this div - paddings become 0px without making animation (5..4..3..2..1). How to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are after a [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) as opposed to an animation.

Just set the initial styling, and change it when hovering over the element like so:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8hgqvt8/)

```
.element {
    height:40px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-bottom-color:#F5B7B8;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.element:hover {
    border-bottom-color:#FB7A7D;
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
}
```

Comment: Well, you are welcome.

Just not want to make another subject, there is one more easy question - how to make fading out effect slower, and fading in faster?